# What does .NET Memory "Gen X Heap Size" .NET performance counters measure exacly?

Tags: .net, memory, garbage-collection

Is that "the sum of all objects allocated" or is it "amount of memory allocated from the operating system for storing objects". Or is it something else?

I think it is memory allocated from the OS, but would like a confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generation heap size measures the total allocated memory of the managed portion of all .NET objects currently in that particular garbage collection generation.

See [this](http://wiki.codinglight.com/(S(k25r0umgrbkmdd55ww53dcb4))/GarbageCollector.ashx) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the Generation number. For Gen 0 it measures the max memory you can allocate:

[MSDN quote :](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2tyfybc(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Displays the maximum bytes that can be allocated in generation 0;
>   
> it does not indicate the current number of bytes allocated in generation 0.

For Gen 1 & 2 it measures the sum of all allocated objects because in these generations objects are actually promoted not allocated.

> Displays the current number of bytes in generation 1;
>   
> this counter does not display the maximum size of generation 1.